# jquery recognize in which row iam

Tags: jquery, count, row

I have a table with thousands of rows.
There are no ids and so on.

Within the tds of the rows I have a link calling a function and passing "this" to get the link object.

Using jQuery it is easy to get the the closest tr and table (and so the tables.rows.length)

1. I want to know as easy in which row I am. OK I could do a loop but does exist any easier possibility?

#

Another table with rows
The rows have mixing className in no structured order tr1 tr2, tr4 maybe clsA, tr3 clsB
and between them are non "class-named" trs or some called separator

2. I want to know which row comes first clsA or clsB -> remember it is not the first sibling etc. there can be empty trs or separator.

-> I want to avoid loops, that's why I ask for some jQuery tricks.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use jQuery to get row's index. There's DOM property 'rowIndex' (which is the fastest way to get row index IMO). See more here http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/prop_tablerow_rowindex.asp

```
$("#TableId td").click(function()
{   
  var index = $(this).parent("tr")[0].rowIndex;
  alert(index);
});
```

Sample here: http://jsbin.com/oroje

Answer (score 1):

If you have an id on the table you can use this:

```
$("#TableId td").click(function()
{   
  var index = $("#TableId tr").index(this.parent("tr"));
});
```

Read more about the index method at http://docs.jquery.com/Core/index